# How to get back the deleted folder and its content on a linux server?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, redhat-enterprise-linux, cvs

I am using a linux (red hat) server and contents gets updated using CVS. A folder was not in CVS and it got deleted/replaced by another content after I run an update. How can I get the deleted content on my linux machine. Is there any data recovery options available on linux servers.

Comment: That depends -- do you run your red hat off a solid state drive? Harddisk? What file system do you use? The success rate of recovering files is generally very low, even more so for dirs...Expect only *parts* to be recovered, at best.

Answer (score 2):

In short you cannot recover these deleted files.

Depending on your filesystem, you can hack to possibly recover parts of your data.
See for instance:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linuxunix-recover-deleted-files.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-ext3-ext4-deleted-files-recovery-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually, deleting a file (or directory) in linux means it is permanently gone, unless you have some kind of a backup.

There are ways to recover deleted files, and if you are lucky, you might get them back. First you need to have a program to recover a deleted file installed, like for example [photorec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec). As soon as you delete the file, unmount the disk, and shut down. Then boot from live CD, and use the recover program. Using [photorec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec) should be straight forward, since it has some kind of ncurses GUI.

Comment: It is deleted from a server which usd rad hat as OS. I cannot shut down or restart it putting a live CD. Are they any other ways of achieving it.

Comment: @NaanuManu Yes, use the backup ;)